# Binding to a UDP socket for IOCP using C

Tags: c, udp, iocp

I am trying to read from a UDP port, from a local (loopback) application, using IOCP. IOCP works fine for TCP/IP, but I am unable to open the socket properly for UDP.

This is what I am doing:

```
// same as for tcp/ip
struct sockaddr_in remoteAddr = { 0 };
remoteAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = LOOPBACK_ADDRESS;
remoteAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
remoteAddr.sin_port = htons(portNumber);

// using SOCK_DGRAM here
SOCKET sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
sock = WSASocketW(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP, 
    NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);

if( sock == INVALID_SOCKET ) {
    LOG("WSASocketW failed: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    return;
}

nRet = WSAConnect(*sock, (const struct sockaddr*)&remoteAddr, sizeof(remoteAddr),
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

if (nRet == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    LOG("WSAConnect failed: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    return;
}

nRet = WSARecv(sock, &wsabuf, 1, NULL, &flags, &overlapped, NULL);
if (nRet == SOCKET_ERROR && (ERROR_IO_PENDING != WSAGetLastError()))
{
    LOG("WSARecv failed: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    return;
}

// no errors of any kind
LOG("seems good so far");
```

Everything passes without errors, but `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` inside the worker loop thread never returns. If I do the same thing to connect to a TCP socket (just replace `SOCK_DGRAM` with `SOCK_STREAM` basically), I get data inside the loop.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

**(Btw)** I know I could use `WSARecvFrom`, but I would like to reuse as much code as possible from the TCP socket. I.e. hopefully, set everything up and then post `WSARecv` calls inside the worker thread regardless of the type of the socket ([`WSARecv` is supposed to work with UDP properly, AFAIK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Do you want to reuse your code or do you want to make it work? UDP is connection-less, so calling `WSAConnect` doesn't make much sense (unless your joining a uni/multicast group). UDP sockets must be bound to a port/interface using `bind`.

Comment: @Wouter: if possible, reuse and make it work, of course, that's why I wrote this question. :) Does this mean I cannot use `WSARecv` with `bind`, only `WSARecvFrom`? Can you post an answer describing this?

Comment: Never used `WSARecv` myself (only `recv()`), but I think you should be able to replace `WSARecvFrom` with `bind()` + `WSARecv`.

Comment: It's even in the docs: [*The WSARecv function receives data from a connected socket or a bound connectionless socket.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688(v=vs.85).aspx), the word *bound* refers to the `bind()` function.

Comment: and where you bind to *IOCP* ?? also for UDP *WSAConnect* senseless and need use *WSARecvFrom* instead  *WSARecv*

Comment: @RbMm: I don't understand the question, I don't "bind to IOCP", I just wanted to see if I can reuse the same code I used for overlapped IO with TCP. As stated on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688(v=vs.85).aspx), `WSARecv` works for both TCP and UDP sockets, why do you find it "senseless"?

Comment: @Lou - for got packets from IOCP when operation complete you need bind file handle (socket) to IOCP - I not view how/where you do this. and WSAConnect senseless I say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it to work, thanks to the comment by @WouterHuysentruit.

Basically, if I want to receive UDP packets using `WSARecv`, I need to `bind`. If I want to send UDP packets using `WSASend`, I need to `connect`. So the following works:

```
if (port_type == incoming_packets)
{
    // bind to port
    ret = bind(*sock, (const struct sockaddr*)&remoteAddr, sizeof(remoteAddr));
    ...
    WSARecv(...);
}
else
{
    // this can send to a loopback udp port which is bound in 
    // a different application
    ret = WSAConnect(*sock, (const struct sockaddr*)&remoteAddr, sizeof(remoteAddr), ...);
    ...
    WSASend(...);
}
```

As others have pointed out, `WSAReceiveFrom`/`WSASendTo` are usually a better choice for UDP, but in this case I can support multiple port types using IOCP transparently.